# What is the correct structure of classes in java?

Tags: java, class, structure

I have been coding in java for about a year and a half, and have made some small games and programs that I think turned out very well. The problem is that I am mostly self taught and I most of my code and class structure is not organized or "correctly structured". This didn't matter to me for the smaller things I made, but if I were to take on a larger project I would want to structure it correctly and make it organized.

In a previous mini-RPG game I had

- Main Class (Main loop + Main method)
- Player Class (containing player position and player stats)
- Engine Class (containing map and collision detection between player and map
- Map Class (containing map data)

My **Main** class contained an instance of **Player** and of **Engine**, and **Engine** had an instance of **Map**. The problem is that **Player** then could't tell the **Engine** where it was, and the **Engine** couldn't adjust **Player's** position and stats when something happened on the **Map**. So I ended up having some static variables and methods in both Player and Engine to get them to communicate.

I guess my overall question is is this the correct structure of classes, and is it correct to use static methods and variables here? If not, how would you structure these classes, or would there need to be more or less classes?

My overall objective is to understand how to structure classes in this previous game so I can better structure classes in a bigger project I want to take on.

Comment: I'd expect the Engine to have references to both Map and Players. It is the class that has the duty of mutating State ( possibly data in Player-Objects ) using information from Map.

Comment: Have a look at the answers underneath. But a quick tip I think would be to look at singletons. I don't know if you're familiar with these, but they can sure be useful. Especially for your `map` and `engine` class.

Comment: If you really are interested to improve on what you call "structure of classes" you may want to read something about "Software Architecture". Mind that there are constructions used in Game-Development that would elsewhere be frowned upon and vice-versa. Uncle Bob's Clean Coder books are also always worth a read.

Comment: This is a great question that's really hard to answer.  If your code isn't too long, consider posting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, or somehow getting a code review from a more experienced developer.

Answer (score 3):

It is a rather broad question, but the general answer is no.

As a rule you shouldn't use static fields to connect instances. (There are a couple of possible exceptions, but as a rule of thumb it's a useful one.) The basic idea of OOP is that everybody has a reference to whoever they want to send messages to. So if a `Player` needs to tell the `Engine` something, it should have a reference to whichever `Engine` instance it belongs to. Or you can redesign your architecture so only `Engine` sends messages to `Map` and `Player`, it's difficult to tell without more detail about your setup whether that would be appropriate in this case.

Another piece of general advice is to try to sit down with a piece of paper, write down the name of all three of your classes and in a separate column write down all the things the system has to do. And then you should try to figure out who's responsible for what. In a good design this decision is simple, if you find yourself shoehorning different things into one class, that's a sign that you should maybe need a more detailed model with more classes.

I would also suggest you take a look at the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and the [publish-subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern), as it might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

Try take take a look at some design-patterns.
Which design pattern you want to use depends on what you prefer. Some can be found [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

I also take it that you are familiar with OOP? Some more general info can be found [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Looking at your specific story, I think a MVC-design would be a nice solution.

MVC meaning Model View Controller.
Here you have your Model, classes holding different forms of data.
Your Controller, controls your Model, contains all the real logic.
And your View, this is the graphic end of your application.

Comment: I also recommend to use event driven programming instead of having only object references. It is very powerful because it looses the coupling between classes.

Comment: True, there are many solutions. For me personally MVC is one the first I learned and a bit more basic in my opinion. I don't know how well known the OP is with coding in general, that's why i suggested MVC. But event driven is surely a good choice too!

Comment: In addition, I think he should use a singleton instance of his `engine` class. This way he can use a static reference in his players.

Comment: There's a lot that can be done **wrong** using singletons. Especially lazy ones and when it comes to multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to put and instance of your player in your engine as well. That way your engine will control everything (the player and the map). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what you described there a few possible ways to handle this.  One would be to use a messaging system.  I would look into Java Messaging Service (JMS).  Another would be to make your app event drive.  Here is a neat little tutorial on how to do this using spring : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/.  Having said that, if your intent is get a better understanding of problem solving using Java, I would first try and mimic these two approaches on your own, without any bulky frameworks.